# Изменение нескольких параметров из другого потока

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть другой поток, в нем должны изменяться контролы окна. А именно Image и ее свойство ToolTip. Код в WPF:

```
<Image x:Name="IconState" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="4,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" Source="Images/ExImage.png" Grid.RowSpan="2" ToolTip="Some Tip"/>
```

Код в C#:

```
FFM.Dispatcher.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate {; FFM.IconState.ToolTip = "Example tip 2"; })); //Обновляем ToolTip
BitmapImage ImageP = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/ExImage2.png", UriKind.Relative)); //Объявляем изображение 
FFM.Dispatcher.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate {; FFM.IconState.Source = ImageP; })); //Меняем изображение
```

На последней строчке у нас возникает исключение: `System.InvalidOperationException: "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток."`

Почему так происходит? Ведь Dispatcher.Invoke не позволяет выполнению кода идти дальше, пока не придет ответ от диспетчера, тоесть ошибки по идее не должно существовать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы создаёте `BitmapImage` не в UI-потоке. Он считается при этом принадлежащим фоновому потоку (это и есть тот самый «другой поток» из вашего сообщения об ошибке), и не может использоваться в других потоках.

Выхода из этой ситуации возможно два:

1. Создавайте его в UI-потоке, используя тот же `Dispatcher`.
2. Открепите ваш `BitmapImage` от создавшего его потока при помощи `ImageP.Freeze()`. При этом, правда, вы не сможете больше менять свойства этого объекта `BitmapImage` (но с хорошими шансами вам это и не нужно).

---

Кстати, вы можете вызывать код более просто синтаксически:

```
FFM.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { FFM.IconState.ToolTip = "Example tip 2"; });
```

или даже

```
FFM.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => FFM.IconState.ToolTip = "Example tip 2");
```

Comment: Можно узнать, как с вами можно связаться, кроме StackOverflow, ибо есть парочка вопросов, которые тут задавать не очень целесообразно, а хочется. P.S. Если у вас есть такое желание, конечно.

Comment: @SKProCH: Простите, я обычно загружен работой, так что лучше на сайте. Например, я бываю в [чате по C#](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--).